# CSS3 (jQUery?) Hide element "a" when it is hovered, just so element "b" might display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two elements:

```
.el-a {}
```

and

```
.el-b {}
```

By default, `el-b` is already hidden, while `el-a` is displaying, what I need to do is once the user hovers the `el-a`, the `el-a` will hide and the `el-b` will appear. Is it possible to achieve that using CSS3, or it can only be achieved with jQuery?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Can you post your HTML tree? if both elements are *same-level* children, [it's possible with CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4502693/2151050)

Comment: I dot, but the code is too big, I'm making one at jsfiddle.

Comment: Not working, but that's the basis: https://jsfiddle.net/wb1gwfe1/11/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, if both el-a and el-b have a common parent:

```css
.el-a a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.el-b a {
  background-color: lightblue;
  opacity: 0;
}
.parent a {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parent:hover .el-a a {
  opacity: 0
}
.parent:hover .el-b a {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="el-a">
    <a href="#">1</a>
  </div>


  <div class="el-b">
    <a href="#">2</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

You didn't specify if you wanted the area that el-a was taking to collapse or not, so I didn't make it collapse, but that can be done as well.  Also, it would be easier if either el-a and el-b were the same dimensions, or el-b occurs before el-a.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with jQuery by using an ID on each element `#el-a` and `#el-b`:

```
$('#el-a').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('#el-b').show();
});
```

It would also work with classes but if multiple items have the class `.el-b`, they will all show when you hover.

Answer (score 0):

The code would look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".el-b").hide();
    $(".el-a").on("mouseover", function() {
       $(".el-b").show();
       $(this).hide();
    }).on("mouseout", function() {
        $(".el-b").hide();
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not working, when I mouse over, the object keeps blinking, like a machine gun.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this approach for multiple items with classes starting with `'el'` as it involves no hardcoding.

```
$('[class*=el]').hover(   // delegate hover event to all elements having css classes starting with 'el'
         function() {   // this function executes when hovered on
            $('[class*=el]').each(function(){ // iterate through each elements having css classes starting with 'el'
              $(this).toggle();  // this basically sets show -> hide , and hide -> show.
            });        
        }, function() { // this function executes when hovered off
             $('[class*=el]').each(function(){
              $(this).toggle();
            });    
        });
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/huy6yvdu/